# How can send multiple params on a get request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

First of all, give thanks for reading my question and try to help me and apologize for my English.

I'm new with Spring and I have this message:

A servlet request to the URI

`http://localhost:8080/backend/v1/streetviewer/search-street?url=backend2?busqueda=name%20street&idioma=es-es%26cantidad=10`

contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using `@FormParam` will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.

My backend send a request to backend2 with one parameter (url), but that url contains 3 parameters. I understand that is reason why say that.

But I was reading that `@FormParam` is used for POST requests and I'm using `@QueryParam`.

```
@GET
@Path(ApiPath.PATH_BACKEND2)
public String getDataFromProdServer(@QueryParam(ApiParam.PARAM_URL) final String externalUrl ) {
    return mapService.ServerRequest(externalUrl);
}
```

How can solve it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be said you are actually using `JAX-RS` Implementation, from `backend2` I asume it is a separate service so I suggest you to use Spring Implementations for consuming the API. `@RequestMapping/@GetMapping and so..`

Coming to the question (With Spring Implementation)

```java
@GetMapping(ApiPath.PATH_BACKEND2)
public String getDataFromProdServer(@RequestParam(ApiParam.PARAM_UR) final String externalUrl) {
  return mapService.serverRequest(externalUrl);
}
```

Comment: Doesnt works in my code but I understand your implementation. And thanks a lot for your help. I really apreciate